# Is it necessary to index columns just for searching in Oracle views?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing

Let's say if there is a small table called `TB_SMALL` that contains 50 rows with simple structure:

```
TB_SMALL
---------------
ID     |  NAME
---------------
......
......
```

and there is another table holding large amount of data called `TB_HUGE`, that contains a million rows:

```
    TB_HUGE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID     |  FIELD 1  |  TB_SMALL_ID  |  FIELD 1  |  ......  |  FIELD n  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
......
......
```

So that `TB_HUGE` has a foreign key indexed to `TB_SMALL`. However, if there is need to join both table just to search by specific `TB_SMALL.name`, which I assume it is a common case, like this

```
SELECT TB_HUGE.* 
FROM TB_HUGE JOIN TB_SMALL ON TB_HUGE.TB_SMALL_ID=TB_SMALL.id
WHERE TB_SMALL.name = "somename";
```

is it necessary to index `TB_SMALL.NAME` column?

*** may be it is not a good example, as the query can change to

```
WHERE TB_HUGE.TB_SMALL_ID EXIST (SELECT ID FROM TB_SMALL WHERE NAME="somename")
```

but above case is just to illustrate whether it is necessary to index column on small table if join with large tables.

Comment: "is it necessary"   No, it will work without an index.   Is it required for good performance?   Try it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not **need** to for performance reasons, since the whole of TB_SMALL probably fits into a single block or two and can be accessed by a full scan just as fast as by an index (maybe faster).  However:

1. To preserve data integrity, every table should have a primary key, and a primary key requires an index, so in fact you should have an index anyway. (In fact, TB_SMALL would be a good candidate for being an [index-organized table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables012.htm#ADMIN01506) (IOT)).
2. Since the table is small, having an index won't be a big waste of space, so you may as well index it and let the optimizer decide whether or not to use it.

Comment: thank you. Do you think it is also necessary to place index for TB_SMALL.name field, if the where condition check name value in the joining query?

Comment: No (again, unless this needs to be unique, in which case a unique constraint should be added and this needs an index to support it).